# Unknown Leaking Hose behind Volvo engine

Tags: leak, volvo, part-identification, hose, identify-this

There's a hose behind the engine that connects to some fitting that passes through the firewall on an old Volvo XC90 that seems to be leaking oil. I can't identify what that part is.

Does power steering fluid have any need to go past the firewall? What hoses and fluids can one typically expect to traverse the firewall of a vehicle?

[image: Hose in perspective of the engine]

[image: Large segment of hose shown]

[image: Close up on the hose attached to something passing through the firewall]

[image: Close up to oily fitting]

Here's a portion of a [video](https://youtu.be/VDJGOlCfj-Y?t=21) by another fella where this hose comes into view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is an air conditioning refrigerant pipe.  Does the air-con work?

Looks like its part 8 in the diagram below, which can be examined [here](https://www.volvopartswebstore.com/showAssembly.aspx?ukey_assembly=243694&ukey_product=1140248).

[image: AC System with highlighted hose]

There's a couple of variations on the hose...

```
30767197 Tube low pressure CH 153069- CH -300083. With rear air conditioning. 
30767196 Tube low pressure CH 300076. Without rear air conditioning.
8623265  Tube CH 300077- low pressure Without rear air conditioning.
30730670 Tube low pressure CH -153068 With rear air conditioning.
9162350  Tube low pressure Without rear air conditioning CH -153068.
```

Comment: Aha, you're absolutely right. AC seemed fine during the test drive. But it was only experienced for a brief time before I shut it off to better listen to the car.